# I want to know about English grammar's passive and active voices?

Tags: grammar, passive-voice, spoken-english, active-voice

> Organization was formed to achieve specific goals.

Is it passive voice or active voice? If it's passive voice then what is it expressed in an active voice?

Comment: Yes, passive. Some committee formed the organization. Even if you say "The organization was formed by the committee," it's still passive.

Answer (score 2):

While you can usually rephrase a clause with an active transitive verb into an equivalent passive, the reverse is not always possible.

So, the active form  {subject} {verb} {object}  becomes the passive  {object} {be-verb} {past participle} (by {subject}).

> The man ate an apple. -> An apple was eaten by the man.

But if the "by" phrase is not present, you can't convert from passive to active unless you use words like "someone" or "something".

> An apple was eaten. -> *Someone* ate an apple.

In your case you might use "Some people", since forming an organisation usually needs many people.

> Some people formed an organisation to achieve specific goals.

Note that the word "organisation" needs a determiner like "a" or "the".